# images are not diplay from server when i use url through json

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 // here is my code     
        NSData *memberJson = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rotaryrdz.com/app/ios/mob_allmembers.php",kBaseURL]]];

// link shows data argument not used by format string     

    NSDictionary* json = nil;

    //        id json;
    if (memberJson) {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:memberJson
                options:kNilOptions
                error:nil];
    }

    //4
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //code executed on the main queue
        //5
        [self buildArrayWithJson: json];
    });



} );

UIButton * menuButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[menuButton setFrame:CGRectMake(275.0f,0.0f, 45.0f,45.0f)];
[menuButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showPopUP) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:menuButton];    


}
```

Comment: what the problem u faced..., I got the response from your URL, Can u show the image path (server Path)

Comment: actually images are in my server but not display in table list through detail

Comment: show your self buildArrayWithJson method